# Placement of the "Favourite Star" on mobile browsers

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, mobile-web, bookmarks

I like the placement of the "Favourite Star" below the voting arrows. That is, when I am on a bigger screen. As soon as I surf the trinity via my iPod Touch, I have to zoom very deeply to be able to NOT hit the downvote arrow while trying to star a question.

So, what are the options (to position the star somewhere else):

- a bit more space between the voting arrows and the star
- postion the star above the arrows (so the "faulty" vote would be an upvote instead of a downvote .. which is ok since i am staring this question anyway :))
- position it somewhere else

Comment: I also have problems accidentally hitting the Question title (thus refreshing the entire page over a slow network connection) instead of hitting the Up vote button.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't mind an iPhone version of SO to remedy this instead. Seems more appropriate (though harder to implement)

Comment: i am more with this one as well. a question on a mobile browser will fill up the screen almost entirely. the star could be positioned then with a wider margin-top (as @Kobi suggested).

Comment: See my answer below for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try StackMobile!

http://stackmobile.com/

*Supports all trilogy sites!*

Comment: +1 for the great shameless plug ;-)

Comment: yes, nice workaround but looks "non-interactive" for me. since i am aiming to reopen all closed pseudo-humor-posts and thus overruling ivo, this is essential for me :)

btw, the "page 1 2 3" stuff on the list of users .. the numbers are too small to hit exactly. almost the same problem as with the favourite star, just horizontally problematic :)

Comment: @akira: Ya... the API is read-only at the moment, so my app is limited to just displaying the data. I am making a note of the page numbering problem. I'll probably just increase the font size.

Answer (score 1):

This will need a tiny CSS fix. I'm not quite sure how you'd use it though:

```
.star-off, .star-on {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My iPhone's due in a few days so I might come back and cast my vote then.  I have skinny fingers though so it might not be as much of an issue for me.

With regards to moving it above the arrows, some might favourite a question they downvoted so that they can find it easily again later to follow up on, so you're just "moving the problem" if you do that.  I think moving it somewhere else is also a bad idea, it looks nice where it is now and it's in context (vote, score, favourite).

That leaves your first option.  This is completely unnecessary for desktop PCs, so server-side checking of the user-agent should be done to include an extra rule (as [Chris T suggests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55420/placement-of-the-favourite-star-discussion/55422#55422)).

Comment: You can use CSS media queries to change CSS based on the screen size instead of server-side detection. (Media queries are often combined with server-side detection, but they do not require server-side detection.)