# Are the Star and Down Vote UI Elements too close to each other?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, mobile-web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Placement of the “Favourite Star” on mobile browsers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55420/placement-of-the-favourite-star-on-mobile-browsers)

While visiting Stackoverflow.com on my iPhone, I hit the Star on a question but instead it clicked the Down Vote. The main problem is that Down Votes take a bit off your reputation, which is very costly in such a mistake. Any suggestions to fix this?

[image]